# Orthogonal projection proof problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

So the textbook says: $P$ is the matrix of an orthogonal projection if and only if $P$ is symmetric and $P = P^2$

So I got confused about $P = P^2$ part
I know :

$P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ for a matrix $A$ whose column vectors form a basis for the column space of $P$

$P^T = (A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T)^T = A((A^TA)^{-1})^TA^T = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T = P$

But for $P^2$, I tried:

$P^2=PP=(A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T) (A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T)=A(A^{T}A)^{-1} ((A^T A(A^TA)^{-1} )A^T$=$ A(A^TA)^{-1} (A(A^TA)^{-1} *A(A^TA)^{-1} ) A^T$

But how can this turns out to equal  $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T =P$?

Comment: What is your definition of projection matrix? Btw, the terms $(A^T A)^{-1} (A^T A)$ clearly cancel (after rearanging parentheses..) which is all you need. I don't understand your second-last line, however.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=P^{T}=P^{2}$, and let V be the column space of P.

We know that P projects onto that space. Certainly for any vector $x$, we have $x=Px+(x-Px)$, and $Px$ is certainly in the column space. We need to show that $x-Px$ is orthogonal to the column space.

So let $y$ be any vector in V, so that $y=Pz$ for some $z$. Then $y(x-Px)=y^{T}x-y^{T}Px=z^{T}P^{T}x-z^{T}P^{T}Px=z^{T}Px-z^{T}P^{2}x=z^{T}Px-z^{T}Px=0$

Reference: https://staff.imsa.edu/~fogel/LinAlg/PDF/32%20General%20Projections.pdf