# How do I prove that this is an orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I have no idea how to do this.
I'm pretty sure the formula for the orthogonal projection onto V is $A(A^TA)^-1 A^T$

Comment: And what is $A$? The question is: how did you define $\operatorname{proj}_V$?

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1705822/265466

Answer (score 2):

A projection satisfies
$$
P^2=P\tag{1}
$$
That means that a projection is the identity on its range.

Furthermore, an orthogonal projection also requires that the difference between the original vector and the projection is orthogonal to the range of the projection. That is,
$$
P^T(Px-x)=0\tag{2}
$$
Thus $P^TP=P^T$. Taking transposes, we get $P^TP=P$. Thus,
$$
P^T=P\tag{3}
$$

So we can test for an orthogonal projection by verifying $(1)$ and $(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\mathbb R^n = V\oplus V^\perp$. So, if $x\in\mathbb R^n$, you have $x = v + w$ with unique vectors $v\in V$ and $w\in V^\perp$. I assume that you defined $\operatorname{proj}_V(x) := v$.

You will have to show two things:

1. If $P = \operatorname{proj}_V$ is the projection (matrix) onto $V$ then $P$ is selfadjoint and $P^2 = P$.
2. If $P$ is selfadjoint and $P^2 = P$, then $P = \operatorname{proj}_V$ with some subspace $V$.

Let us begin with 1. We have $Px = v$. Now, the unique representation of $v$ with respect to the decomposition $\mathbb R^n = V\oplus V^\perp$ is $v = v + 0$. Thus $Pv = v$. Therefore, you get $P^2x = P(Px) = Pv = v = Px$. Thus $P^2 = P$. For the selfadjointness observe that if $x = v_x + w_x$ and $y = v_y + w_y$, then
$$
\langle Px,y\rangle = \langle v_x,v_y+w_y\rangle = \langle v_x,v_y\rangle = \langle x,v_y\rangle = \langle x,Py\rangle.
$$
Hence, $P$ is selfadjoint.

2. Define $V := \operatorname{im}(P)$. Let $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Then $x - Px\in V^\perp$. Indeed, let $w\in V$ be arbitrary. Then $w = Py$ for some $y$. Thus,
   \begin{align*}
   \langle x-Px,w\rangle
   &= \langle x-Px,Py\rangle = \langle x,Py\rangle - \langle Px,Py\rangle\\
   &= \langle x,Py\rangle - \langle x,P^2y\rangle = \langle x,Py\rangle - \langle x,Py\rangle = 0,
   \end{align*}
   where we have used that $P$ is selfadjoint and $P^2 = P$. Thus, $x = Px + (x-Px)$ is the unique representation of $x$ with respect to the decomposition $\mathbb R^n = V\oplus V^\perp$. This proves $Px = \operatorname{proj}_V(x)$.